# OpenLayers 3: OverviewMap Control

Tags: openlayers-3

Currently the overviewmap control in openlayers3 acts like a minimap where you can see the actions that you are doing on the main map.

Has anyone tried, or knows if it is possible to use the overviewmap **both ways**? Meaning that you can select the red rectangle from the overviewmap and move it around the overviewmap, and the main map view being updated with the actions from the overviewmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible, but there's an opened discussion about this in OL3 GitHub: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3753

Contributions would be welcome.